logging values in vmap function in jax
This question is an extension of my original question here. So using the callback function, I am able to log values. Here is the code:
from collections import defaultdict
# this is my activation pattern logger
class ActivationLogger:
    def __init__(self, epoch):
       self.reset(epoch)

    def __call__(self, layer, activations):
        assert isinstance(layer, int), f"Layer must be an integer, not {type(layer)}"
        self.activations[layer].extend(np.asarray(activations).ravel().tolist())
                    jax.lax.stop_gradient(activations[i]))

    def reset(self, epoch):
        self.epoch = epoch
        self.activations = defaultdict(list)

activation_logger = ActivationLogger(epoch=1)

...

def predict(params, image):
    # per-example predictions
    activations = image
    for l, (w, b) in enumerate(params[:-1]):
        outputs = jnp.dot(w, activations) + b
        activations = jnp.maximum(0, outputs)
        jax.debug.callback(activation_logger, l+1, jax.lax.stop_gradient(activations))


    final_w, final_b = params[-1]
    logits = jnp.dot(final_w, activations) + final_b
    return logits - logsumexp(logits)

batched_predict = jax.vmap(
        predict, 
        in_axes=(None, 0), 
        out_axes=0)

@jax.jit
def loss(params, images, targets):
  preds = batched_predict(params, images)
  return -jnp.mean(preds * targets)


Clearly, the l parameter in the for loop is an integer but I get the following error:
assert isinstance(layer, int), f"Layer must be an integer, not {type(layer)}"

I believe this is due to jax.vmap which vectorizes the loop. So the l gets aggregated and gets passed as a jax array. This is a problem since I want to log these values by layer. I could just use jnp.array or np.array to store them and process them later but is this the only option available?
Thanks in advance.

As of JAX v0.4.27, all arguments in callbacks are passes as jax arrays (see CHANGELOG).
If your logger requires an integer rather than an array, you can convert the value to an integer before passing it to the logger. For example, something like this:
jax.debug.callback(lambda i, x: activation_logger(int(i), x), l+1, activations)


hmm this seems to work but this slows down the training speed by a lot for some reason

Yes, that’s expected. Adding callbacks in general can prevent the compiler from fusing computations,, and also indices a runtime penalty while the process sends data to the host. I’d suggest using it only for debugging purposes.
